# Improved Method of Finding and replacing Strings in an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have the following array:

```
["cat", "dog", "cow"]
```

I want to replace the values of each with a new string.

```
["tiger", "wolf", "diary"]
```

Currently I am traversing through a for loop and checking to see if a string that needs its name to be changed exists, if it does then I am replacing it with the new value. While a for loop works, I am wondering if there's a nicer way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an object with the replacing to do, you can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var replace = {
  'cat': 'tiger',
  'dog': 'wolf',
  'cow': 'diary',
};

var starter = ["cat", "dog", "cow"];

var final = starter.map(value => replace[value] || value);
 
console.log(final)
```

If the string is not in the `replace` object, `replace[value]` is `undefined`, so `replace[value] || value` is evaluet do `value` itself.

Anyway, the `for` is definitely more performing, at least on node.js, accordingly to benchmark.js:

```
Array.map x 2,818,799 ops/sec ±1.90% (76 runs sampled)
for array x 9,549,635 ops/sec ±1.86% (79 runs sampled)
Fastest is for array
```

Here the code I used for the test

```
var Benchmark = require('benchmark');
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

suite
.add('Array.map', function() {
  var replace = {
    'cat': 'tiger',
    'dog': 'wolf',
    'cow': 'diary',
  };

  var starter = ["cat", "dog", "cow"];

  var final = starter.map(value => replace[value] || value);
})
.add('for array', function() {
  var replace = {
    'cat': 'tiger',
    'dog': 'wolf',
    'cow': 'diary',
  };

  var starter = ["cat", "dog", "cow"];

  var final = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < starter.length; i++) {
    final.push(replace[starter[i]] || starter[i]);
  }
})
// add listeners
.on('cycle', function(event) {
  console.log(String(event.target));
})
.on('complete', function() {
  console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
})
// run async
.run({ 'async': true });
```

Comment: @lost9123193 I did some tries, and the `for` is more performing (see the updated answer) at least on how I implemented it

Comment: ah I see, I probably will not have more than 300 possible entries, but in terms of scalability  would you suggest I stick to the for loop?

Comment: Well, this is definitely premature optimization and it depends also a lot on how much you need performances. We are still talking of 2 millions operations/sec! I use a lot `map()` and `filter()` in my code, because is definitely better looking than a for - but I do not need incredibly performance. I'm quite sure `map()` is good enough in your case too. I only wanted to show you the entire situation :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function transform(str){
   //logic to transform goes here
}

var massaged = myArr.map(transform);
```

Maybe thats what youre asking for?

map reference here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map